# Connect Vpon Adwhirl on Iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, adwhirl

I try to connect Vpon Adwhirl on Iphone ，the ad show on my iphone app，but
I have a question because i see an error

```
2012-06-29 13:24:21.001 Butter[3083:17603] Cannot create ad network config from {
    key = "";
    nid = ;
    nname = "";
    priority = ;
    type =;
    weight = ;
}: Ad network type 21 not supported, no adapter found
```

"Ad network type 21 not supported ",What's it mean?

I tap Ad network but my DeveloperPanel was not change?

Please give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Ad network 21 identifies the BrightRoll network.  This error means you have not included either the BrightRoll adapter or the BrightRoll SDK in your application.